# tkinter Label does not respect justify option?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class PopupTk(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, title="Notification", msg="New information", duration=2):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.duration = duration
        close_button = Button(self, text="C", command=self.master.destroy)
        close_button.pack(side=LEFT)
        title_label = Label(self, text=title)
        title_label.config(justify=LEFT)
        title_label.pack()
        msg_label = Label(self, text=msg)
        msg_label.config(justify=LEFT)
        msg_label.pack()
        self.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES, padx=10, pady=10)

        # get screen width and height
        ws = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()
        hs = self.master.winfo_screenheight()
        w = 300
        h = 100
        # calculate position x, y
        x = ws - w
        y = hs - h
        self.master.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
        self.master.overrideredirect(True)
        self.master.lift()

    def auto_close(self):
        msec_until_close = self.duration * 1000
        self.master.after(msec_until_close, self.master.destroy)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()

    sp = PopupTk(root, duration=3)
    sp.auto_close()
    root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here is the result:

[image]

It's still center-aligned (the default).

I am using python 3.4 and have tested this on osx and ubuntu 14.04, btw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem you have is that `justify` only affects labels with more than one line of text. The option you want to use instead of `justify` is `anchor`. However, that's not your only problem.

Here's a simple way to start to debug problems like this: add a temporary border around your widgets. This lets you see where the boundaries are, making it possible to visualize whether it is the text that is centered, or the widget that is centered (or both)

```
title_label.config(borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
...
msg_label.config(borderwidth=1, relief="solid")
```

Doing that, it becomes obvious that the problem isn't that the text isn't left-aligned in the widget, it's that the widget is centered in its section of the frame.

A quick fix might be to use the `anchor` attribute when packing the widgets. That will force the widget to the left side of the parcel it's been allotted.

```
title_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
msg_label.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
```